# Insert data using multi array

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

The scenario is

Original source is look like (it is without the attribute email , name....etc):

```
a@a.com          leo
foodil@g.com     NULL
```

I would like to insert an record like this:

Firstly, i have an array of what datafield i need to insert

```
 $field = Array ( [0] => Email [1] => Name )
```

Secondly, I have an array of mail

```
$mail = Array ( [0] => a@a.com [1] => foodil@g.com )
```

=============================================================================

Lastly, I have an multi dimension array that has datafield e.g. Name,

```
$set = Array ( [1] => Array ( [1] => leo [4] => NULL ) )
```

**however, It can be  more than one field, 
eg. it can be also have a field of phone (and also address, geneder...whatever) , then it will be:**

It is random index because the counting skip the mail column

eg.

```
leo     a@a.com          4343343
NULL    foodil@g.com     3453343


   $field = Array ( [0] => Email [1] => Name  [2] => Phone ) 

   $set = Array ( [0] => Array ( [1] => leo [4] => NULL )  [2] => Array ( [1] => 4343343 [4] => 3453343 ))
```

=============================================================================

The problem is , how to insert in the scenario like this? :
The query should look like this

**And the mail will be tested, only if it is true, then insert.
eg. a@a.com is invalid, then i have to skip leo and 4343343**

```
$query="INSERT INTO subscriber (Email,Name,Phone) VALUES ($mail[] , $set[][], $set[][])";
```

Comment: Not really following what $set is and why it has random indexes?

Comment: what's the source of the original arrays, i bet you format them to make this a lot easier.

Comment: updated the question, hope can slove your doubt PorridgeBear and Dagonn thank you.

Comment: How is a@a.com invalid.?? I mean whats your criterion for invalid and valid email??

Comment: Why is there an index `[4]` after `[1]`? What does `NULL` mean? And someone can have multiple phone numbers, is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this it will give 2D array.
After getting array make foreach loop & insert into database.

```
$field = array ( '0' => 'Email', '1' => 'Name',  '2' =>'Phone' ) ;
$mail = array ( '0' => 'a@a.com', '1' => 'foodil@g.com' );
$set = array ( '0' => array ( '1' => 'leo', '4' => NULL ),  '2' => array ( '1' => '4343343', '4' => '3453343' )) ;

$res = array();
$key1= array_keys($mail);
foreach($key1 as $a=>$key){
    if(array_key_exists($key, $set)){
        $res[$a]['Email'] =$mail[$key]; 
        $res[$a]['Name'] = $set[$key]['1'];
        $res[$a]['Phone'] = $set[$key]['4'];
        unset($set[$key]);
    }else{
        $res[$a]['Email'] =$mail[$key];
        $res[$a]['Name'] = '';
        $res[$a]['Phone'] = '';
    }
}    
$total = count($res);
foreach($set as $q){
    $res[$total]['Email'] ='';     
    $res[$total]['Name'] = $q[1];
    $res[$total]['Phone'] = $q[4];
    $total++;
}
```